# Electronic switches rated for 300A @ 12VDC

Tags: mosfet

I have a 250A alternator and I want to charge two 200A batteries. I intend to charge each battery in turn for 30 minutes using a timer, but I don't want to switch between the batteries using mechanical contacts rated at 300A. I'd rather switch them using electronic switches like MOSFET, FET, SCR, triacs or transistors. **How can I switch the batteries using those devices?**

Comment: Step 1: buy fire extinguisher :)

Comment: Step 2: Begin testing with a 250**mA** power source, not the 250A alternator.

Comment: You want to just turn on and off circuits or regulation with PWM? If just turn on and off - it will be not that hard.

Answer (score 4):

**About big transistors**

Well... big transistors are still transistors and act like transistors.

There are dedicated ICs with logic input to drive high power transistors. These drivers are designed to charge (turn on) and discharge (turn off) transistor gate very fast. Transistor gate can be considered as capacitor. In big transistors gate has higher capacity, there are higher charge and discharge currents, but... idea is the same.

When gate is charged - transistor is turned on. When gate is empty - transistor is turned off. If gate is partially charged - it is partially turned on and it has some resistance which causes power loss which is very undesireable when switching high currents.

High power transistor drivers are usually more complicated because they have some additional protection to prevent fire or other damage in not normal conditions (like power [brown-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity))) etc.

**Big transistor drivers**

If you are looking for big transistor driver - you can google for "IGBT driver ic" I found:

- [ISO5500 from Texas](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso5500.pdf)
- [MC33154 from Motorola](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/208/501602_DS.pdf)
- [AUIR08152S from IR](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/auir08152s.pdf)

First one is not suitable for you (datasheet says "transistors up to 150A", but maybe someone else will be interested.

Last one is for automotive, maybe it will be suitable for you, but everything depends on transistors you use.

Most of ICs like these can drive very big MOSFET and IGBT transistors. They usually need positive and negative supply, because negative voltage applied to transistor gate can discharge gate faster (gate can be considered as capacitor), and transistor can be turned off faster to reduce switching power loss ("transistor partially opened" time is shorter).

Power supply for big transistor driver and driver itself should be very reliable, because if it fails during transition (turning on or off) - your precious expensive transistor will blow up.

**Safety!**

Few important things when you are playing with 3kW circuit:

- make sure you have fire extinguisher :)
- never(!) allow your transistor to be partially open at high current (like 300A) because it will explode
- use some protection glasses, some shield/casing for circuit and/or keep safe distance
- use some kind of "kill switch" that turns off everything in case of fire or other problems

**Keep in mind that alternator is huge inductance in circuit**

You may have **problems with alternator and voltage regulator in it** if you switch very big load very fast. You may have to modify alternator voltage regulator to reduce excitation current when you are switching load. Alternator has huge inductance and there will be huge [back-EMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) when you suddenly connect or disconnect 250A load. So... maybe your circuit is 12V, but back-EMF can be much higher.

**Troubleshooting big transistor driver**

Using oscilloscope to see what is going on between drain and source while switching is highly recommended.

Comment: I was going to suggest a FET (or maybe several in parallel.)  Is an IGBT the right choice?  I had this idea they were for higher reverse voltages... like doing AC switching.  But I don't know much about power.  (3 Amps is a lot of current to me.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold You are right, FET would be better, because IGBT transistors have high voltage drop (1.5-2.5V). For 12V system that would be too much. I changed my answer.